# How to execute GuiMacro from ConEmu child

Tags: conemu

I am using ConEmu as an Irssi host on windows and so far it works perfect!
I would like to implement an additional feature though through the GuiMacro system that ConEmu exposes.

From inside irssi, through its perl scripting system, i am able to find the irssi.exe instance pid (from the $$ variable). Now using this, how can i retrieve the ConEmuC.exe pid that communicates the Irssi instance, to make the following sample line work?:

```
ConEmuC.exe -Guimacro:<ConEmuC.exe PID> MsgBox("Notification text")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that there is an %ConEmuServerPID% exactly for this work!

I should had read better the documentation.

Comment: ConEmuPID is expected here

Comment: By the way, do you know why either using ConEmuPID or ConEmuServerPID with FlashWindow does not flash the tray icon?

Comment: What?? FlashWindow takes HWND as argument, but not a PID. More, it do dot flash "tray icon" at all! Only taskbar buttons are able to flash.